# Is there a more efficient way to do this string color mixer?

Tags: c++, algorithm, comparison

I am working on a homework assignment where we are supposed to ask the user for 2 primary colors (red, blue, and yellow). They cannot be numerical values, they must be words. It should then take the two colors and "mix" them together to give the resulting color. The code i have posted below works, however i am wondering if there is a more efficient way to do this because i can see this way being very problematic if one had to combine more than two colors together.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string color1="", color2="";

    try
    {
        cout << "Please input your first color" << endl;
        getline(cin, color1);

        if (color1 != "red" || "yellow" || "blue"){
            throw "Invalid Color";
        }
    }
    catch (string e)
    {
        cout << e << endl; 
        system("pause");
        return -1;
    }
    try
    {
        cout << "Please input your second color" << endl;
        getline(cin, color2);

        if (color2 != "red" || "yellow" || "blue"){
            throw "Invalid Color";
        }
    }
    catch (string e)
    {
        cout << e << endl;
        system("pause");
        return -1;
    }

    if (color1=="red")
    {
        if (color2 == "red")
        {
            cout << "red";
        }
        if (color2 == "blue")
        {
            cout << "purple" << endl;
        }
        if (color2 == "yellow")
        {
            cout << "orange" << endl;
        }
    }
    else if (color1 == "blue")
    {
        if (color2 == "red")
        {
            cout << "purple" << endl;
        }
        if (color2 == "blue")
        {
            cout << "blue"
        }
        if (color2 == "yellow")
        {
            cout << "green" << endl;
        }
    }
    else if (color1 == "yellow")
    {
        if (color2 == "red")
        {
            cout << "orange" << endl;
        }
        if (color2 == "blue")
        {
            cout << "green" << endl;
        }
        if (color2 == "yellow")
        {
            cout << "Yellow" << endl;
        }
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is a lot of repetition in the input section. Looks like there is a `AskUserForColor()` function there begging to be written. Also, the color strings are repeated a lot--these could be constants. Better yet, create a Colors enum and write a function for converting a string to the matching member. Finally, there's more repetition in the mixing section. If you define a standard ordering for color1 vs color2, you could avoid needing to have (eg) a yellow-red case in addition to a red-yellow.

Comment: I'm likewise voting for a move to codereview.se; but initial thoughts include: using exceptions for error handling is weird here - just handle the input error in the `if`-block. For three colours this approach seems OK, but enforcing an ordering would help. For scalability, I'd seriously consider a `map<pair<string, string>, string>` lookup table, to convert a pair of colours into their combination. You could enforce ordering or not at your discretion.

Comment: You always throw an exception regardless of the input, so I doubt that it works.

Comment: I can't believe I missed that. Yes, `color1 != "red" || "yellow" || "blue"` does not do what you thing it does (it always succeeds, since "yellow" is truthy)

Comment: Pesonally, I think you could go a long way only using strings for colors in the in and out. `typedef enum
{
    RED=0x1,
    BLUE=0x2,
    YELLOW=0x4,
    PURPLE=RED|BLUE,
    ORANGE=RED|YELLOW,
    GREEN=BLUE|YELLOW
} Color;` and then parse it in and format it out.